# PyCharm to open new file in the tab right next to the right of current-active tab?

Tags: tabs, editor, pycharm

Currently with PyCharm 2016.03, when I open new file, the tab opened at the end of the tab pane.

I [google](https://www.google.com.vn/#q=pycharm+how+to+open+new+file+tab+on+the+right+of+current-active+tab) and see one [old post](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206369799-Open-new-tabs-last-) about this - it was a `open right next` feature in the past and changed to `open at the end` now.

So if you know, if possible, how to switch tab-opening mode in PyCharm, please share!

Answer (score 1):

That config is no longer available (at least in the 5.0.5 Pro version). You still have tabs appearance and closing policy configs under `Editor -> General -> Editor Tabs` menu, but no opening policy.

As a workaround you can left-click and drag a tab in whichever position you like.

Comment: In fact, the opened tabs are sorted alphabeltically

Comment: And dragging tabs to re-order it of course is annoying and I have to ask here. Thanks any way